# php validate date function using explode

Tags: php

I was trying to define a function to validate date entered in dd/mm/yyyy format.
I am trying to use the inbuilt function checkdate() and explode() to supply values to checkdate()
This is the code:

```
    <?php
function validate_date($date){
$array = explode('/',$date,3);
checkdate($array[1],$array[0],$array[2]);
}
?>
```

I get an error:

Warning: checkdate() expects exactly 3 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\officespace\mdm\Create_Individual.php on line 57

Please can someone indicate where exactly I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You're showing an error on line 57, but your code only has 6 lines.

Comment: try to var_dump($array); to see what you have.

Comment: This code has no errors.

Comment: what's the formate of the date u r using is dd/mm/yy, or mm/dd/yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bool** [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) ( int *$month* , int *$day* , int *$year* )

http://codepad.org/hKZP726r

```
<?php
function validate_date($date){
    $array = explode('/',$date,3);
    echo "\$array = ". var_export($array, true) . "\n";
    $ret = checkdate($array[1],$array[0],$array[2]);
    echo "\$ret = " . var_export($ret, true) . "\n";
    return $ret;
}

validate_date('24/11/2011');  // dd/mm/yyyy
```

**Output:**

```
$array = array (
  0 => '24',
  1 => '11',
  2 => '2011',
)
$ret = true
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should count the value before you pass to the function.

```
<?php
function validate_date($date){
$array = explode('/',$date,3);
if(count($array) === 3){
checkdate($array[1],$array[0],$array[2]);
}
}
?>
```